# ¿Cómo solucionar BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Tengo Spring Security 5 en Spring Boot 2.0.3

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm= " + getRealmName());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        //response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println("Http Status 401 " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("Proyecto");

        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

configuración de seguridad:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    private Usuario usuario;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUsuarioDetalleService();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withUser(usuario.getUsuarioNombre())
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(usuario.getClave()))
                .roles(usuario.getRol().getNombre());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final CustomFilter tokenFilter = new CustomFilter();
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("admin")

                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Filtro personalziado :

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

Servicio de detalles de usuario :

```
@Service
public class MyUsuarioDetalleService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usuarionombre) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findByUsuarionombre(usuarionombre);

        UserBuilder builder = null;

        if (usuario != null) {

            builder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(usuario.getUsuarioNombre());
            builder.password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(usuario.getClave()));

            builder.authorities(getGrantedAuthorities((Collection<Rol>) usuario));
            //throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Nombre Usuario" + usuarionombre+" No encontrado ");
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Nombre Usuario" + usuarionombre + " No encontrado ");
        }

        return builder.build();
        //return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(usuario.getUsuarioNombre(),usuario.getClave(),getGrantedAuthorities(usuario));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Collection<Rol> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Rol role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getNombre()));

        }

        return authorities;

    }
}
```

la salida del error es el siguiente :

> ```
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
>   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
>   com.ventura.app.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
>   'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     ... 25 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at
>   com.ventura.app.config.SpringSecurityConfiguration.configure(SpringSecurityConfiguration.java:49)
>   ~[classes/:na]  at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:265)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:201)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:321)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   com.ventura.app.config.SpringSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a15102ea.init(<generated>)
>   ~[classes/:na]  at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd4731c2.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd4731c2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3829ce79.invoke(<generated>)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd4731c2.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
>   ~[spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     ... 26 common frames
>   omitted
> ```

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: si pude resolverlo pero si hay otra solución puedes publicar también gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución esta en la siguientes lineas código

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usuarionombre) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Usuario usuario=usuarioRepository.findByUsuarionombre(usuarionombre);

    UserBuilder  builder=null;

    if(usuario!=null){

        builder=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(usuario.getUsuarioNombre());
        builder.password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(usuario.getClave()));
        builder.roles(usuario.getRol().getNombre());
        //builder.authorities(getGrantedAuthorities((Collection<Rol>) usuario));

    }else{
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Nombre Usuario" + usuarionombre+" No encontrado ");
    }

    return builder.build();

}
```

Configuración de seguridad:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;



    private Usuario usuario;


     @Bean
      public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUsuarioDetalleService();
      };

      @Bean
      public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      };

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());



    }

@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final CustomFilter tokenFilter = new CustomFilter();
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http            
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest().hasRole("admin")

            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }




}
```